# How to configure Express with Nginx

Tags: express, nginx

I've configured Nginx with Express according to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04) article.

This is my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_time;

    listen 8080;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        # default port, could be changed if you use next with custom server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The first request I send to the Node app through Nginx is ok, but after that, any request takes 60 seconds to respond. This is the logs:

```
192.168.13.27 - - [20/Feb/2019:09:16:01 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 302276 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"rt=0.324 uct="0.000" uht="0.002" urt="0.002"
192.168.13.27 - - [20/Feb/2019:09:17:04 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"rt=60.003 uct="0.000, 0.000" uht="60.002, 0.001" urt="60.002, 0.001"
```

If I make a direct request to the node app on port 4000 everything is ok.

I've searched StackOverflow to look further but the problem still exists. I tried to lower the `proxy_read_timeout` and `proxy_connect_timeout` values, but it only works on static files specified in Express `static` module and other Express routes throw 504 Gateway Timeout error. How can I find and resolve the problem?

Comment: Per configuration provided you are missing proper server_name which is used for identifying domain you access. also try to change `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;` instead of trying localhost. If you dont have domain yet make `server_name <some_name> default`; default (this will work if there is no other default domain in place then u have to change it for a testing )

Comment: Also are you using express for serving files ? thus "/" route or is it serving as REST endpoints ? Id so you should namespace it to `/api` or something